# Can't start jboss server; NoClassDefFoundError: com/tibco/tibrv/TibrvException

Tags: java, jboss, tibco-rv

I am trying to setup our jboss server but I get this error even after downloading and installing rendezvous 64bit.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tibco/tibrv/TibrvException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2398)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2708)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1987)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was using the wrong library. My company had their own tib library with modifications.